# Does ASP.NET Core app support desktop applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

My project is based on PHP tool. I need to fetch the data from that tool using ASP.NET C# to convert this to desktop application. Will  ASP.NET Core app support desktop applications?

Or suggest any technology which will support desktop application.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you mean. ASP.NET is a web framework - you can make requests *to* it from desktop applications, but it isn't a desktop application framework itself. Please edit your question to be much more precise about what you mean. (It's also entirely unclear to me where PHP comes in...)

Comment: You can run Windows Desktop application based on **.NET Core** - but that's **not** ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core is the **web stack** - web app and APIs  - for desktop apps you need to look into Winforms, WPF, WinUI3, MAUI on .NET Core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) application using .Net Core, but for now, you may only use Visual Studio as an IDE (Rides does not support it).

See this for more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-wpf?view=vs-2022

I personally prefer to create desktop apps using Electron, which is a cross-platform JavaScript-based framework.
See Electron's documentations here: https://www.electronjs.org/